# SSIS FTP Task error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to exec a SSIS FTP task package through SQL server 2008 with the dtexec xp_cmdshell command.  But I am keep getting the following error codes:
   Code: 0xC001700A
   Code: 0xC0016020
   Code: 0xC0010018

I have also try to perform it by creating a job in SQL Server, but same result came up.  How can I resolve this issue? Or am I missing any steps during the process of creating my FTP task in SSIS in order for me to FTP file in SQL Server? Because, I can FTP the file through the SSIS environment but not in SQL Server.

Comment: Have you tried executing this through the SSIS Debugger in Visual Studio?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345164.aspx, 0xC0016020 is DTS_E_PACKAGEMIGRATIONFAILED whilst 0xC001700A is DTS_E_INVALIDVERSIONNUMBER. This sounds like something more fundamental than an FTP error ... what EXACT version of SQL Server are you (a) running the package on and (b) was the package developed under?

Comment: I am currently running on MS SQL Server 2008 and developed my package within MS VS 2008. –

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using Visual Studio 2008 to create your package.

Comment: I am currently running on MS SQL Server 2008 and developed my package within MS VS 2008.